# Average time for a brute force shuffling algorithm to terminate

Tags: algorithms

I was going through the Udacity CS212 class on program design, and the teacher([Peter Norvig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Norvig)) was explaining why a specific shuffling algorithm was inefficient([shown here](http://youtu.be/cx1FXMXgroU?t=24s)).

The algorithm consists of picking random pairs of cards in a deck, swapping them, and repeating that process until every card has been swapped at least once.

In the [answer video](http://youtu.be/bblNAUU8wL8), he claims that the algorithm will take on average $N^2$ swaps to terminate where N is the number of cards being shuffled.

I however, ran some tests and did some Googling, and the algorithm seems to terminate after $O(N*log(N))$.

I am hesitant to correct someone as experienced as Norvig, but he just seems to be flat out wrong.

Comment: The algorithm is not only inefficient but also wrong, as it doesn't produce a uniform distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  number of random draws required to select all the cards at least once is the Coupon Collector's Problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem.  The expected number of draws is $O(n \log n)$, so I think you are right.